# Jquery calling an object with a dynamically created variable

Tags: jquery, oop

I think I must be searching for this incorrectly because I have not found any solutions yet. I am using wiris editor to allow users to create rich textareas that are then populated by other users. Each instance of wiris has a dynamically populated name based on how many editors have already been created. $t is just a counter.

```
editor<?php echo $t ?> = com.wiris.jsEditor.JsEditor.newInstance({'language': 'en'});
```

I then need to retrieve the contents of each specific editor.

If I type the literal object name

```
var ml = editor3.getMathML();
```

everything works fine, but when I try to use a variable to access the dynamically created object name

```
var dynamicName = 'editor'+t;
    var ml = dynamicName.getMathML();
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object editor3 has no method 'getMathML'
```

How can I use the string created in dynamicName to call the editor3 object?

Comment: `dynamicName` is a string.  You need to use something like `eval` for javascript to evaluate (and execute) the command.  You could try something like `var editor = eval(dynamicName); editor.getMathML();`.  It may work.  But be careful with `eval` because if someone *can* inject nasty javascript in there, it will be executed.

Comment: Another thought - you mentioned jQuery in the title.  Is there some other way to access the editor by using a dom selector?  You might be better off to do something like `var editor_selector = '#id_of_editor' + t; var ml = $(editor_selector).getMathML()`.  I"m not sure if this will work without seeing how the editors are setup and how the jQuery plugin works.  But if you can, this kind of method would be safer than an `eval` as i suggested above.

Comment: Thanks, eval does the trick. I am going to try and find a work around like you mentioned that will work for my conditions but the t variable that is being evaluated is a counter, not an input field, therefore I manage to make it secure with eval.

Comment: What's your reason to not use arrays?

Answer (score 0):

I think `dynamicName` is not your object: it should be the string `editor3` but I can not explain the error message; I thought the message should be `Object dynamicName has no method 'getMathML'...` maybe in the message the name *dynamicName* is replaced by the return value of method `toString` of object *dynamicName*, so the string *editor3* itself...

Anyway, you can try the following:

```
var dynamicObj = eval('editor' + t);
var ml = dynamicObj.getMathML();
```

Comment: For the error message, the console never prints the variable name, it always creates a string representation of the value. And for strings, that's the content of the string itself.